# Change the scope of a attribute

Tags: database, ce-1.7.0.2, localisation

A extension created a extra tab in my category menu. With this code:

```
$setup->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'menutopdescription1', array(
    'group'         => 'General',
    'input'         => 'textarea',
    'type'          => 'text',
    'label'         => 'Topmenu description',
    'backend'       => '',
    'visible'       => 1,
    'required'      => 0,
    'is_wysiwyg_enabled' => 1,
    'visible_on_front' => 1,
    'note'=>'Category description for top menu dropdown',
    'is_html_allowed_on_front' => 1,
    'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
));
```

This results in a global scope. Now I would like to change it to "website".
So I can easily translate it for my other websites.

This attribute isn't visible in the attribute list of Magento, so I have to make the changes in the database.
Which key do I have to change?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Create an upgrade script with this code:

```
$setup->updateAttribute('catalog_category', 'menutopdescription1', 'is_global', Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_WEBSITE);
```

$setup is an instance of Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup or Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup.

If you want to change the db directly (I don't recommend it) you need to change the field `is_global` to `2` from the table `catalog_eav_attribute` for the record with the id the same as your attribute has in the `eav_attribute` table.

Comment: You can replace `'catalog_category'` with `Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::ENTITY`

Comment: @Dan. I would If I could but I don't want to. :D. now seriously...that will work also. thanks

Comment: The snippet above did not work for me. Instead what I had to do was: `$installer->updateAttribute('Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::ENTITY', 'menutopdescription1', 'is_global', '0');`

Comment: @LouisBataillard I've edited the answer (waiting on approval). 'global' is used during attribute creation, which is passed through a _prepareValues() method. And modified to 'is_global'. Why the developers do this I don't know (i find it confusing to change how we reference the same thing). 'is_global' is the actual attribute's "attribute". And this is the key we want to reference during updates to attributes.

Comment: What if i have to change scope to Globle instaed website in DB?

Answer (score 0):

Can add small script and run for change Scope

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require_once './app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();

$attributeCode = 'is_active';
$setup = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_setup', 'core_setup');
$setup->updateAttribute('catalog_category', $attributeCode, 'is_global', Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL);
```

where $attributeCode - attribute code of category.